# Get ImportError: cannot import name 'InstallCommand' when run command `pipenv shell`

Tags: python, pipenv

I get the `ImportError` when I do the following steps:

I install pipenv

```
pip install pipenv
```

Next, I create virtual environment for python and activate

```
python -m venv env
source ./env/Scripts/activate
```

Last, I run command

```
pipenv shell
```

And I get ImportError

Full trackback:

```
$ pipenv shell
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ndqnhat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\ndqnhat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\workplace\nhatndq\env\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\options.py", line 56, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 420, in shell
    pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror,
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2431, in do_shell
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 594, in ensure_project
    system=system_or_exists,
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 296, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile(python=python)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\project.py", line 682, in create_pipfile
    from .vendor.pip_shims.shims import InstallCommand
ImportError: cannot import name 'InstallCommand'
(env) 
ndqnhat@DNDW-NDQNHAT MINGW64 /c/workplace/nhatndq
$ pipenv install
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ndqnhat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\ndqnhat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\workplace\nhatndq\env\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\options.py", line 56, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 241, in install
    site_packages=state.site_packages,
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1972, in do_install
    site_packages=site_packages,
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 594, in ensure_project
    system=system_or_exists,
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 296, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile(python=python)
  File "c:\workplace\nhatndq\env\lib\site-packages\pipenv\project.py", line 682, in create_pipfile
    from .vendor.pip_shims.shims import InstallCommand
ImportError: cannot import name 'InstallCommand'
```

How can I resolve it?? Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @gitaarik.

Remove your current environment.

> python -m pipenv --rm

What I did is that I used python3.7 in every single reference.
(I was working with twitchio and I got the same issue.)

> sudo python3.7 -m pip install pipenv

> sudo python3.7 -m pipenv --rm

> sudo python3.7 -m pipenv --python 3.7

Using twitchio

> sudo python3.7 -m pipenv install twitchio

> sudo python3.7 -m pipenv run python3.7 bot.py

Note: I end up on this because I realized that twitchio requires Python 3.7+ So I reference python3.7 every place I use it.
https://github.com/TwitchIO/TwitchIO

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the commands `python -m pip` and `python -m pipenv` instead of `pip` and `pipenv`. This can sometimes resolve issues. Also try to remove the virtualenv and re-create it:

```
python -m pip install pipenv
python -m pipenv --rm

# Maybe restart your shell here to be sure the environment variables are reset

python -m pipenv install

# In case it doesn't find, or use the correct Python binary, specify it:

python -m pipenv install --python=<python-bin-path>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the default python version of the Machine.
You can remove the issue by setting up a default python version that you will use.

```
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1
RUN update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
RUN curl -s https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && \
python get-pip.py --force-reinstall && \ rm get-pip.py
RUN pip3 install pipenv
RUN pipenv --python 3.6
```

Note:

1. python3.x version could be anything you are using.
2. you have to `apt install python3.x` before these command.